# UITableViewHeaderFooterView doesn't dealloc when UITableView is released

Tags: ios, uitableview

I don't know why. The usage is normal.

1. RegisterClass forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier in viewDidLoad
2. `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
3. `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

that's all. but the leak detector [MLeaksFinder](https://github.com/Zepo/MLeaksFinder) alert that UITableViewHeaderFooterView is leaking. In Instruments allocation summary the UITableViewHeaderFooterView is persisted when UITableView has already been released.

This occurs on iOS9 and iOS10. What's the possible reason it doesn't get released??

ARC of course

show the code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.dataSource.count == 0 || section != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    XXXHistoryHeader *view = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:[XXXHistoryHeader reuseIdentifier]];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MZDApplicationFrame.size.width, 95);
    return view;
}
```

My table only has 1 section 1 section header. I already tried to init with nil reuseIdentifier It doesn't work

```
@interface XXXHistoryHeader : UITableViewHeaderFooterView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *count;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *money;

- (void)setCount:(NSString *)count totalMoney:(NSString *)money;

+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end

@implementation XXXHistoryHeader

+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}

- (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //not important
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCount:(NSString *)count totalMoney:(NSString *)money
{
   //not important
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc!!!");
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to show the code in your viewForHeader

Answer (score 0):

Take Your tableview as `weak` reference, it would may fix your problem,some how it unable to release its memory where it suppose to be, So by taking weak reference it may help your code to release the entire tableview after removing the class object from the stack.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not using storyboard or xib